# Restore postgres schema from .sql dump file without role and/or permissions?

Tags: database, postgresql, vagrant, psql

I receive the following error when attempting to restore a postgres database schema from an .sql dump file created on another server:

`REVOKE psql:backup.sql:158885: ERROR:  role "server_name" does not exist`

The dump file was created using `pg_dump -U username "server_name" -n schema_name > schema_name.sql`

How can I create a dump file without role and/or permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By utilizing the flags `--no-owner` and `--no-acl`

> Do not output
>   commands to set ownership of objects to match the original database.
>   By default, pg_restore issues ALTER OWNER or SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION
>   statements to set ownership of created schema elements. These
>   statements will fail unless the initial connection to the database is
>   made by a superuser (or the same user that owns all of the objects in
>   the script). With -O, any user name can be used for the initial
>   connection, and this user will own all the created objects.

Prevent restoration of access privileges (grant/revoke commands):

```
pg_dump --no-owner --no-acl -U username "server_name" -n schema > schema.sql
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgrestore.html